# Main bundle Assets in Swift package previews

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

[image]

I have the following *(screenshot)* project setup. Basically simple application with some **SwiftUI views placed in the local SPM packages**.

While I'm building the application for a real device/simulator everything is good, all assets are loaded properly.
SwiftUI **preview located in the local package though is not able to display the image from the main bundle** *(screenshot)*.

I'm wondering if there is some way to load main bundle assets to SwiftUI previews as well.

Comment: Is your image a template image or default? I had this issue and had to change it to template

Comment: No difference if it's a template/original/default. Each of them invisible in the preview.

Comment: Regarding access to main bundle assets: You have access to the binary's bundle assets, but in your case it is not the main bundle, it is the `.module` Bundle, which is a specific Bundle existing for swift packages. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The assets are in the Main bundle not in the package, so specifying Bundle.module doesn't make any sense. When you run the app it works just fine, but the preview doesn't work. @SzymonW did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @SeanRobinson159 I wasn't able to fix it, I ended up without previews at all

Comment: @SzymonW please read my answer down below, if you are still interested in a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the assets to your package library instead of your main target.

Notice the `bundle: .module` parameter in `Image`. This is necessary so that the system knows which target you are targeting, in this case the libraries bundle (module).

This works on devices and also in the previews.

To me it is kind of esoteric when you access an asset in the app bundle from a separate library.

Library assets should really live in the lib itself otherwise there is no complete separation of the library from the app.

If you ever use the library in a different target or app you then need to make sure the asset is copied there, too.

[image: This is how it works]

This is how the `Package.swift` must look like:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            dependencies: [],
            resources: [.copy("Assets.xcassets")]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: I know that I can keep my assets in the package itself but since I use these to build modules of a single app I would love to share all of my assets from the main bundle. Please keep in mind that this solution works just fine on the device/simulator, the issue appears only for Xcode previews.

Comment: I don't see any `Bundle.module`..? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle